# Query an Amazon DynamoDB by column named "timestamp" (a reserved word)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with column named "timestamp" and am trying to query by date. I don't have control over changing the column name.

```
var params = {
    TableName : 'REPORT_CARD',

    KeyConditionExpression: "timestamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":startDate": ""+startDate,
        ":endDate": ""+endDate
    }     
}
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: ValidationException: Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: timestamp

Is there a workaround for this besides renaming the "timestamp" column?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Firstly, assuming the table **'REPORT_CARD'** is defined with **partition key** as `timestamp`, you can use only **equality operator (i.e. '=')** in `KeyConditionExpression` for querying data by partition key.

You may use `BETWEEN` if the `timestamp` is defined as **sort key** in the table.

Regarding the keyword error, you can use `ExpressionAttributeNames` to provide the attribute name `timestamp`. Example below:-

```js
var params = {
    TableName: 'REPORT_CARD',

    KeyConditionExpression: "parition_key_attr = :partition_val AND #timestamp BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#timestamp": "timestamp" },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':partition_val': "somevalue",
        ":startDate": startDate,
        ":endDate": endDate
    }
```