# Can I conditionally serde(rename) a field based on what serializer is being used?

Tags: rust, serde

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    // for DynamoDB, name is reserved, so use "foo_name" as the field name
    #[serde(rename = "foo_name")]
    name: String,
}
```

When I write to DynamoDB, I need to rename the `name` field. When I serialize as a JSON string, I'd like to not have it named `foo_name`.

While I could use an intermediate struct, is there another way to conditionalize the rename, so that the JSON string has `{"name": "some-name"}`?

Comment: TL;DR: no, you cannot.

Comment: note: Serde allows "specifying independent names for serialization vs deserialization" https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html -- would that help you?

Comment: No, I'm using serde to move serialize/deserialize from a DynamoDB, so names need to match. What I can do is serialize (via from) into another struct where the name isn't renamed and then serialize that to JSON.

Comment: I think you can escape the keyword in DynamDB like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42425621/4593433), so that you don't need to rename the field.

Comment: There is a urlo thread about conditionally skipping fields, but the techniques should transfer to renames too: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/multiple-variants-of-serde-derive-outputs/61776